# Update query executing more that 75 mins

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`. I want to update `TABLE_B` status field if `TABLE_A`  name doesn't exists. When I execute the query below it is taking more than 75 mins. I have indexes on `Table_B` columns `b_id`, `m_id` and `status`. I am not sure how to execute this in secs. Did I do anything wrong while updating indexed columns? `Table_B` stats are showed in attached image.

```
UPDATE TABLE_B 
SET    status = 3 
WHERE  ( status = 1 
          OR status IS NULL ) 
       AND b_id = 39 
       AND m_id = 2 
       AND NAME NOT IN (SELECT NAME 
                        FROM   TABLE_A 
                        WHERE  b_id = 39 
                               AND m_id = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Please replace the image with text.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) and 
 
 [**How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: Table_A need index for `b_id` and  `m_id` Table_B need composite index for `(b_id, m_id, name, status)` We need to see the query explain to help you further

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, we already have indexes on Table_A columns b_id and m_id. Can I create column level index and composite index for same column?

Comment: What is level? You can create how many index you want. Do you know how use `EXPLAIN`? My suggestion is forget the `UPDATE` try optimize a `SELECT`  add one condition each time and adjust the index accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could try using  a  left join where don't match instead of a NOT IN

but be sure you have proper composite index  on

```
  TABLE_A  columns  ( NAME,b_id, m_id)
  TABLE_B columns (NAME, b_id, m_id, status)

UPDATE TABLE_B 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A ON TABLE_B.NAME = TABLE_A.NAME AND TABLE_A.b_id = 39  and TABLE_A.m_id
SET    status = 3 
WHERE  ( status = 1  OR status IS NULL ) 
AND TABLE_B.b_id = 39 
AND TABLE_B.m_id = 2 
AND TABLE_A.NAME IS NULL
```